# Nylas Api integration with Office 365 external login

Tags: c#, office365

I am trying to login with office 365 from [nylas api](https://docs.nylas.com/reference) integration i am getting logged in but when nylas callback url is called then error comes like this:

> Status 500:An internal error occurred. If this issue persists, please contact support and copy/paste this request_uid: "

my app in azure oauth is unverified.

it is already working with gmail.

it should login with microsoft account and sync email.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with their Node SDK.

Comment: @NitinKumar have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you might have a misconfiguration in your OAuth settings for Office 365. Take a look at [this guide](https://docs.nylas.com/docs/o365-oauth-setup) to make sure everything is setup properly. Specifically, make sure you check the following items:

- Enable all of the appropriate permissions in Azure for the data your app is trying to access.
- Generate OAuth credentials for your Nylas app within Azure and add the OAuth client ID and client secret to the app configuration settings in the Nylas dashboard.
- Check your manifest JSON in Azure to make sure there aren't any conflicts.

One last thing, check your Callback URI configurations for your Nylas app in the dashboard. It's unlikely this is the problem since you're able to login with other accounts, but you need to make sure that if you're using a different login flow for Office 365 that the appropriate Callback URI is listed in the Nylas dashboard.

If none of these work, HTTP 500 errors are often related to upstream email provider misconfiguration or problems. [Nylas support](https://docs.nylas.com/docs/nylas-support) can help you investigate the issue further.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that you might have a misconfiguration in your OAuth settings for Office 365. Take a look at [this guide](https://docs.nylas.com/docs/o365-oauth-setup) to make sure everything is setup properly. Specifically, make sure you check the following items:

- Enable all of the appropriate permissions in Azure for the data your app is trying to access.
- Generate OAuth credentials for your Nylas app within Azure and add the OAuth client ID and client secret to the app configuration settings in the Nylas dashboard.
- Check your manifest JSON in Azure to make sure there aren't any conflicts.

If none of these work, HTTP 500 errors are often related to upstream email provider misconfiguration or problems. [Nylas support](https://docs.nylas.com/docs/nylas-support) can help you investigate the issue further